# how to allow access to login page without authentication from filter

Tags: java, spring, filter

the filter is always checking for authentication for the login page and I don't know how to configure it.

here is the **AppFilter.java** (I couldn't post all the code):

```
@Singleton
public class AppFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    try {
      final String appLocale = AppSettings.get().get(AvailableAppSettings.APPLICATION_LOCALE, null);
      APP_LOCALE = appLocale == null ? null : new Locale(appLocale);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }

  public static String getBaseURL() {
    return BASE_URL.get();
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    BASE_URL.set(computeBaseUrl(request));
    LANGUAGE.set(request.getLocale());
    try {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
      LANGUAGE.remove();
      BASE_URL.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `doFilter()` in order to check if the requested URL belongs to the list of predefined excluded URLs, if so then just forward the request to the next filter or servlet in the chain, otherwise do whatever you want to do.

Here is the code:

```
@Singleton
public class AppFilter implements Filter {

    private List<String> excludedUrls;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        excludedUrls = Arrays.asList(YOUR_LOGIN_URL);
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
String path = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getServletPath();
        
        if(!excludedUrls.contains(path))
        {
            // if url does not match your login url do what you want to do..
        }
        
        // else forward the request to the next filter or servlet in the chain.
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```